# How to retrieve only N sub documents from Mongo document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The MongoDB document contains the historical price of a product. It is structured as follows:

```
{
    "pricehistory": {
        "2020-08-31T00:00:00": {
            "vendorA": 53532,
            "vendorB": 58787,
            "mdcomputers": 58929
        },
        "2020-08-30T00:00:00": {
            "vendorA": 36450,
            "vendorB": 39378,
            "vendorC": 54174
        },
        "2020-08-29T00:00:00": {
            "vendorA": 54308,
            "vendorB": 52188,
            "vendorC": 30349
        },
        "2020-08-28T00:00:00": {
            "vendorA": 30806,
            "vendorB": 44070,
            "vendorC": 39591
        },
        ..... 

    }
}
```

How to retrieve the objects whose properties are greater than "2020-08-01T00:00:00"? Should the property be saved in ISODate format?